# Need some exciting, semi-dark intro music for a game

Tags: soundtrack

I'm creating a game, and I'm looking for a source of free, royalty-free music for the soundtrack.  Can you recommend sites?

Comment: Specific music recommendations are considered off-topic here.  I edited your question to make it more general, and potentially of interest to a wider audience.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't looking to purchase from a music library, your best general source for royalty-free music is probably [Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/about/program-areas/arts-culture/arts-culture-resources/music-communities/).  The best-known individual producer of free, royalty-free music is probably [Kevin MacLeod](https://incompetech.com/music/).